# Creating pricing - generate decimal based number from value in pence/cents

Tags: javascript, parsing, currency

I'm aware of the use of `.toFixed()` to add two decimal places, but what I need to do is convert a value like `3540` (pence, or cents) into `36.40` to represent it's pound/dollar value.

```
return val.toFixed(2);
```

This just makes `3640.00` - how do I parse to add two decimal places to the *existing* number?

And is there a way to also round this up at the same time? So `3640` = `37`?

Comment: Well, consider `parseFloat(3640/100).toFixed(2)`

Comment: so basic division and Math.ceil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, just divide by 100:

```
return (val / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Or if it needs to be rounded up

```
return (Math.ceil(val / 100)).toFixed(2);
```